# Find and replace value in XML (dynamically)

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML code (that's a script for jmeter load testing), ex.:

```
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
     <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
     <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController">
       <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
       <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">10</stringProp>
     </elementProp>
     <intProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1000</intProp>
     <intProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</intProp>
     <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1363247040000</longProp>
     <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1363247040000</longProp>
     <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
     <longProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">0</longProp>
     <longProp name="ThreadGroup.delay">0</longProp>
   </ThreadGroup>
```

I wish to change params, that are named as **LoopController.loops** and **ThreadGroup.num_threads** from a constant values (like now - 10 and 1000) for dynamical values (for example 10+10 and 1000+100) in a loop.

I'm newbie in Python, sorry.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: This forum is best when you post what you've tried, and ask about problems you're having, rather than requesting that someone write the code for you.   What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's far from clear exactly what it is you want to do, but this solution uses the [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) library to parse your example XML data and make the changes you describe.

The XPath expression `//*` simply finds every element in the data, and the subsequent `for` loop checks the `name` attribute of each element found to see if it is one of those wanted. If there is a match then the `text` attribute is changed to the values you described. Clearly any string you like can be put in here.

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('thread_group.xml', parser)

for e in tree.xpath('//*'):
    name = e.get('name')
    if name == 'LoopController.loops':
        e.text = '10+10'
    elif name == 'ThreadGroup.num_threads':
        e.text = '1000+1000'


print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

**output**

```
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
  <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
  <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController">
    <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">10+10</stringProp>
  </elementProp>
  <intProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1000+1000</intProp>
  <intProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</intProp>
  <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1363247040000</longProp>
  <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1363247040000</longProp>
  <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
  <longProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">0</longProp>
  <longProp name="ThreadGroup.delay">0</longProp>
</ThreadGroup>
```